# Almost ready to downgrade over frustration

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, suspend

I have two problems that no one will seem to answer. It involves two things: network connectivity and key features such as restart and shutdown not working.

1. The network won't re-enable after suspend. This is really annoying. I use features such as apache to serve locally. When network connectivity gets lost after wake, people get angry.
2. I have two screens, and ever since I attached the second one, features, more specifically the bottom three options in the settings menu (top right), aren't working. However, the terminal does work.

I need someone to help me, or I'm going to have to go back to, most likely, 12.04. I have all updates currently installed, and I'm getting sick of these problems.

Laptop: Acer Aspire 5250.

Everything worked on every past version of Ubuntu from 12.04LTS to 13.04 (currently 13.10)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the hardware you are using at all, so a quick fix to problem #1 would be to disable hardware suspend and just use the screensaver lock instead...  Some hardware can disable or disconnect after shutting down for a while, bugs like this are usually fixed eventually...

As for problem #2, pop into Terminal and see if the command 'sudo shutdown -h now' actually shuts down the computer and 'sudo reboot' restarts it ok.

Comment: Thanks but I already knew all of that... I have to do a sudo shutdown in order for shutdown/restart to work